# WP8 Xamarin App hangs on SplashScreen on First start

Tags: c#, xamarin, windows-phone, mvvmcross, splash-screen

I have a strange situation. My windowsphone 8 app build with Xamarin and MvvmCross runs perfect from my debugger (visual studio).

Then I submit the app to the app store (beta store by the way). After that I downloaded it on my device and started the app. The splashscreen shows off... but thats it (I waited for about 5 minutes). No crash and no other information about what happens.

When I then go back with my backbutton or my start-button and restart the app. Everything works fine. This situation only occurs on the first time I start my app after downloading from the store.

1. Question: Is there someone with same issues?
2. Question: Is there a tool or something which I can use to log the device to get some more information?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are submitting to the Windows Phone App Store and the OS on the phone running the app is **greater than v7.0.7355**., you should be able to retrieve the crash dump data from the Windows Phone Dev Centre.

This will only cover crashes within an application and not the underlying OS code.

For more information see: [Crash count reports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206725%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Check you don't have any code in the debug-only section of the App.xaml.cs

e.g. if your init code sits inside a block starting `if ( Debugger.IsAttached )`